# Jquery - Json - ToolTip return object object

Tags: html, jquery, tippyjs

```
tippy('.message, {
    theme: 'css',
    placement: 'left',
    content:getListMessage
    });
                
function getListMessage() {
var json = data.messageId; 
var array = json.split(" "); 
var title = "<h1>" +  array[0] + "</h1>" + "<br>" + array[1] + "<br>" + "<h4>" + array[2] + "</h4>"; 
return title ;
}
```

Hello everybody,
I have the following problem that I show in code, in practice it does not return the concatenated result to me by transforming it into HTML in practice format the text at will.
In content, I noticed that the tooltip still does not format me
in content does not give me anything back only [object object]
as you can see from the code in JSON I converted it to an array so that for each element I can insert tags.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your relevant HTML/JS to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you done to debug this so far? I'd start by using some breakpoints (or at least `console.log()`) in your `getListMessage` function to inspect your `json` and `array` variables. That should quickly point you toward a fix.

Comment: all data is returned in these variables:
json
array
title
the problem that in the content attribute is not populated content as I should do.

Comment: ok, again I'd ask what you've done to debug that? What if you change `getListMessage()` method to only `return "<h1>test</h1>";`? Does that work or not? This will help you narrow the scope of where your script isn't working as expected. Have you checked the documentation (https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/constructor/)?

Comment: If you get `object Object` then it means you (or your `tippy`) is trying to coerce an `object` as a `string` (as in `console.log("" + {})`.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates the issue*?  (and doesn't have **obvious** syntax errors, which are no doubt just typos...).  Your code, as presented (minus obvious error) gives an error because `data` is missing.  https://jsfiddle.net/7hm35snf/3/  but works fine as straight html https://jsfiddle.net/7hm35snf/2/